# Can Async Task write in internal storage android?

Tags: file, download, android-asynctask, android-internal-storage

Hi i need to download a file from url and save in internal storage,so the download process run in async task. 
First, I have tried to write a string in a file with async task but give me error: Failed to create oat file.
The same code work without task, so my question is i must download the file in external storage and after move in internal?

```
    private void writeInFile() {
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    String text = "TEXT";
    try {
        output = openFileOutput("nameFile.abc",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        output.write(text.getBytes());
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But if i call this function in doInBackground of class that extend AsyncTask i receive the error.

```
    LicenzaTask mt = new LicenzaTask(this);
    mt.execute();


public class LicenzaTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Context mContext;

public LicenzaTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    mContext = mainActivity;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    modifyFile();

    return null;
}


private void modifyFile() {
    File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + "nome.abc");
    String text = "text";
    BufferedWriter output = null;
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        }
    }
```